# PHP: find latin word

Tags: php

My text:

```
$string = "Hello World سلام How are you من ایرانی هستم This تست برای ارسال است";
```

I want get this output:

```
[0]=>'Hello World',[1]=>'How are you',[2]=>'This'
```

How i can ?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Like this:</s>

```
preg_replace('/[^\x21-\x7E]*[^\x20-\x7E][^\x21-\x7E]*/',"\n", $string)
```

If you actually want to get an array with the lines, use `preg_split` instead:

```
preg_split('/[^\x21-\x7E]*[^\x20-\x7E][^\x21-\x7E]*/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

That regex means to replace any sequence of non-printable ASCII characters, possibly including spaces in or around it, with a single newline.

Comment: Thank you. but i want get output in array like : `[0]=>'Hello World',[1]=>'How are you',[2]=>'This'`

Comment: Can you add that to the body of your question? My answer as it stands now does exactly what the body of your question currently says.

Comment: Ok, i add to in my question

Comment: Thank you. but if i use number in persian lang, not remove it `سلام 3 خوبی`. in word is persian, but 3 number not delete

Comment: If a number is in between Latin text and non-Latin text (such as "Hello 3 سلام"), which do you want it to be counted as part of?

Comment: Non Latin is better

Answer (score 0):

You should use Regex to achieve that (There are several Regex you can write):

```
preg_split("/(\b\W{2,})/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

- **\b** : Any word boundary
- **\W** : Any non-word character
- **\W{2,}** : 2 or more of *\W*

Link of your example(***Select Preg_Split***) : https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ptD

**[Regex tutorial](https://www.jotform.com/blog/php-regular-expressions/)**

Comment: Hal kon bash :)

Comment: damet garm. agha age adade 3 ro vasate jomle farsi bezarim hazf nemishe va harfe englisi tashkhis mide `سلام 3 خوبی`. in jomle farsie, bayad 3 ro nayare to array

Comment: @TootiTooti what about a number between English word and Persian word ? for example سلام 3 how are you? or Persian word between English word and letter?

Comment: @TootiTooti Haji ziyad farsi harf nazn gir midan